# Hiding folder with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this structure in my PHP script

root folder alias htdocs

- > backend/..

- > frontend/..

- > index.php

- > login.php

However I would like to make the system more secure, so thinking about to hide /backend from the url. The admin is inside /backend, so example /backend/managerusers.php

Currently tried the next solution

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)backend 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/$1 [L]
```

But it didn't work. If I removed the /backend the index.php file in the root folder (htdocs) went to loop.

Comment: It is not really clear what you actually try to get as a target. The rule looks like you are trying to rewrite _to_ the `/backend` folder which contradicts your description...

Comment: So what would you want to happen if `managerusers.php` is a file which exists on both the front and back end?

Comment: Now, i am confused, what do you prefer in this case?

Comment: @arkascha i would like to remove the backend from the url :)

ex:. http://localhost/backend/index.php to http://localhost/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# To externally redirect /backend/index.php to /backend/index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+backend/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally rewrite /index.php to /backend/index.php
RewriteRule ^(?!backend/|login)(.*)$ backend/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: still giving redirect loop :( (if logged in there is no problem, since the /backend seems hidden, but if i do log out and visit login pages, it's do a loop..

Comment: hmm, might be let me check :(

Comment: actually worked fine, but i wasn't able to use login feature. (login.php in root dir) But the backend folder gone and didn't got redirection loop...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^backend/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should remove `backend` from your URLs. Please make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: One more question, before modifying anything. Should i post .htaccess into root or inside backend folder?

Comment: There is no reason that should loop. Have you got anything else in your `.htaccess` that could conflict?

Comment: nope, it's a very new and fresh system :)

can be a problem, if there is an index.php actually in the root folder?

Comment: Ah ok, comment out the other section to test it. It will help you see if that is causing an issue or not.

Comment: 404 .. :D must be problem then

Comment: You're not including the `Options +FollowSymLinks` are you?

Comment: Nope, should i?

Comment: No, I was just checking.